# Convert Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageDefinition to Sitecore.Globalization.Language?

Tags: publishing, multilingual

Since I had to use the following method to retrieve all languages:

```
Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageDefinition.LanguageDefinitions.Definitions()
```

And the `PublishManager.Republish(...)` expects an array of `Languages`, now I'm facing this situation on which I need to convert those types to achieve my goal.

Do you guys know an elegant way of doing that?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you needed to get the `LanguageDefinition`s instead of `Language`s?

Comment: Not really, I was just following the Marek's suggestion on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601351/sitecore-get-list-of-all-languages.

Comment: Ahh. In that case, I'd recommend using @hishaam's suggestion below (`LanguageManager.GetLanguages()`) instead, so you have only the list of languages that Sitecore has available, instead of all languages that are supported on your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below method to get the different languages

```
var source = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var target = Factory.GetDatabase("web");

var languages = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(source).ToArray();

PublishManager.Republish(source, new Database[] { target }, languages.ToArray());
```

This will return a list of Languages that you can use to parse to the Publish Options. Based on this approach, there is no need to parse the language and this will overcome the issue you are experiencing on the following question:- [Why there is no OOTB LanguageDefinition for a Language which name is “en”?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17035/why-there-is-no-ootb-languagedefinition-for-a-language-which-name-is-en)

Comment: That's just perfect, thank you so much Hishaam!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<Language> GetAllLanguages()
{
    return LanguageDefinitions.Definitions.Select(definition => Language.Parse(definition.Name));
}
```